# Panel Data Regression on Biglm in R - Non Linear Model

Tags: r, plm, bigdata

I have following data set which is panel data. Total data is about 78 millions rowcount. I have few more columns of data which I have skipped here.

```
                 date      stockName   PRC VOLUME
2 2016-06-01 09:30:53 ABCD IS Equity 14.25  13957
3 2016-06-01 09:30:54 EFGH IS Equity 14.25  14620
4 2016-06-01 09:31:04 IJKL IS Equity 14.25  14120
5 2016-06-01 09:31:11 MNOP IS Equity 14.25  13820
6 2016-06-01 09:31:47 ABCD IS Equity 14.30  20408
7 2016-06-01 09:31:58 EFGH IS Equity 14.30  29776
```

As far I understood plain `biglm` run is not for panel data. Please correct me if I am wrong. So how can I use it for panel data. Any kind of comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's a pre-programming question where I am seeking advice for programming to run Panel data through biglm in R (non-linear)

Answer (score 1):

The page [Econometrics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html) at CRAN can give you an overview about the packages avaiable for econometric analysis.

As suggestion, I think **lme4**, **nlme** and even **pglm** may be the packages for what you are looking for: nonlinear panel data, despite I don't know much about their performance when you have too much rows.

Although they are written in the *mixed-effect models* jargon, the **plm** vignette gives brief comments about the interchangeability between this terminology and that used by econometricians.

Comment: yes thank you, I am also looking into same packages. But I am not sure about correct prediction power for large scale data.

Comment: If you are looking for fixed effects models (in the panel data/econometrics sense): for the amount of data you have, package `lfe` (command: `felm`) might come in handy as it has a C implementation for the data transformation which is fast.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is estimate a linear model with fixed effects, one possibility is to do it in two steps.

- Step 1: Within-transformation of your outcome and covariates: build within-transformed variables X and Y by subtracting the individual average of each variable from itself
- Step 2: Regression of the within-transformed variables using biglm

Comment: I forgot to mention the model is non-linear

Comment: Could you indicate what the type of the outcome (binary, count,...) is? Also, it would be helpful to know what estimation command you would use if there was no dimension problem.

Comment: to be very specific, I am looking for `plm` like package -- check this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) or tool may be; for performing `panel data regression` through `biglm` in `R`